# How to store String data to a string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Another silly homework question that I cannot seem to solve. I am attempting to store user input string data into a string array but I am receiving an error that "Cannot implicitly convert type "string" to type "int"" despite the fact that nothing in my code (to my knowledge) is suggesting that it needs to be an int type. I'm receiving the error in the last line between the square brackets: playerNames [playerName] = playerName;

Edit: I know that my variables and if statement are messed up, I will fix that as soon as I figure out what is going on with the array issue.

```
    static void InputData(string [] playerNames, int [] playerScore, ref int numPlayers)
    {
        int numberPlayers = 0;
        if (!numberPlayers.Equals("Q"))
            for (numPlayers++; numPlayers < 100;)
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the player...Enter \"Q to exit...");
                string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
                playerNames [playerName] = playerName;
```

Edit: Here is my resolved code for this portion
        static void InputData(string [] playerNames, int [] playerScores, ref int numPlayers)
        {
            string playerName;

```
        for (int i = 0; i != numPlayers; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the player...Enter \"Q to exit...");
                playerName = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!playerName.Equals("Q"))
                    Console.WriteLine("No further user input needed...\n");
                else
                    playerNames[i] = playerName;
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the score of the player...");
                    int playerScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    playerScores[i] = playerScore;
```

My next question to this point is that a user below advised that arrays store integers. I have to store up to 100 player names and 100 player scores. What would any of you suggest?

Comment: could you explain how an integer can be equal to `Q`? besides you are just assigning it to zero !

Comment: `My next question to this point is that a user below advised that arrays store integers.` --- Arrays store whatever type they are defined as storing. However, the index to the value must be an integer. There are other options, but using two arrays is fine.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I misunderstood you. Another random question, I apologize for all of these. But I have read and read my book with no success to these answers. How do you call an array from a different method?

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
playerNames [playerName] = playerName
```

because playerName is a string and cannot be used as an index to the array.

Did you mean:

```
playerNames [numPlayers] = playerName
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work when numberPlayers is a reference to an `int`:

```
!numberPlayers.Equals("Q")
```

... because "Q" is not an `int`.

Comment: Why the downvote? There are multiple problems with the OP's program. This is one of them. The other one is that the array references are using the playerName input, rather than an `int`. Another is that "Q" is not being checked against the input variable, playerName.

Comment: I agree with you. I am resolving that now. That is a simple fix but the issue I am running into is the arrays. I have always struggled with arrays and was hoping that when I took the college courses it would fix my issues...but unfortunately I still am struggling with them.

Comment: @user3479390 use `numPlayers` in the square brackets rather than `playerName`. Array references are integers in C#, not strings.

Comment: Better yet. How do I pass an array as a reference or call it to another method?

Answer (score 1):

The basic `for` loop should looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != numPlayers ; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the player...Enter \"Q to exit...");
    string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
    playerNames [i] = playerName;
    ... // The rest of your loop goes here
}
```

This assumes a fixed number of players. If you want to make it expandable, make a `List<string>` for names and a `List<int>` for scores. Better yet, combine names and scores in a class.

The signature of your function assumes that the two arrays would be expanded. While this is possible in .NET, it's not something that is gone routinely.

Here is how I would change your function without introducing a new class for the player:

```
static void InputData(List<string> playerNames, List<int> playerScore) {
    // The caller is assumed to have assigned non-null lists to the two arguments
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the player...Enter \"Q to exit...");
        string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
        if (playerName == "Q" || playerName == "q") break;
        playerNames.Add(playerName);
        ... // The rest of your loop goes here
    }
}
```

If you pre-allocate arrays of 100 items, change the code as follows:

```
numPlayers = 0;
while (numPlayers = 0 ; numPlayers < 100 ; numPlayers++) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the player...Enter \"Q to exit...");
    string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
    playerNames[numPlayers] = playerName;
    ... // The rest of your loop goes here
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me why this is so much different from what I have and why I am receiving the error? I will be utilizing another array that will require similar input.

Comment: @user3479390 Your assumption about changeability of array sizes is incorrect. Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: I would love to use that for my assignment. But unfortunately I am required to use 2 arrays.

Comment: @user3479390 The you should pre-allocate the arrays - please see the edit.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line

```
playerNames[playerName] =playerName.
```

PlayerNames is a string type array and to access an element of that array you have to provide an  integer value and you are providing a string value.

```
playerNames[int type value here] =playerName
```